# Is there any connection between the Genius Party movies?

Tags: genius-party

Is there any connection between the seven short films that were included in [Genius Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genius_Party)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is no direct connection between any of the 7 Genius party movies, besides their high standard of quality and inspiration, as said by [Rupert Bottenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupert_Bottenberg):

> The seven short films making up **GENIUS PARTY** couldn’t be more diverse, linked only by a high standard of quality and inspiration. Atsuko Fukushima’s intro piece is a fantastic abstraction to soak up with the eyes. Masaaki Yuasa, of **MIND GAME** and **CAT SOUP** fame, brings his distinctive and deceptively simple graphic style and dream-state logic to the table with “Happy Machine,” his spin on a child’s earliest year. Shinji Kimura’s spookier “Deathtic 4,” meanwhile, seems to tap into the creepier corners of a child’s imagination and open up a toybox full of dark delights. Hideki Futamura’s “Limit Cycle” conjures up a vision of virtual reality, while Yuji Fukuyama’s "Doorbell" and "Baby Blue" by Shinichiro Watanabe use understated realism for very surreal purposes. And Shoji Kawamori, with “Shanghai Dragon,” takes the tropes and conventions of traditional anime out for very fun joyride. —﻿Rupert Bottenberg

Source: [Fantasia Festival](http://www.fantasiafestival.com/)'s [2008 program](http://issuu.com/fantasiafestival/docs/fantasia2008) (see p. 119)